# Добавить столбец в датафрейм Pandas с применением apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

1. У меня есть дата фрейм:

```
data = np.array([['United States', 'Russian Federation'],
   ['Russian Federation', 'Uzbekistan'],
   ['Bulgaria', 'Russian Federation'],
   ['Russian Federation', 'Spain'],
   ['Russian Federation', 'Montenegro']])
stack = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['Country_1','Country_2'])
```

Мне необходимо добавить новый столбец Country_3 по следующему правилу: если Country_1 = Russian Federation, то Country_3 равно Country_2. Иначе Country_3 равно Country_1.

Почему я не могу это сделать с помощью `apply`?
Вот мой код:

```
def function(col):
    if 'Russian Federation' in col:
        return stack['Country_2']
    else:
        return stack['Country_1']

stack['Country_3'] = stack['Country_1'].apply(function)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1:** воспользуйтесь методом [Series.mask()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
stack["Country_3"] = \
    stack["Country_1"].mask(stack["Country_1"]=="Russian Federation", stack["Country_2"])
```

**Вариант 2:** воспользуйтесь методом [Series.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
stack["Country_3"] = \
    stack["Country_1"].where(stack["Country_1"]!="Russian Federation", stack["Country_2"])
```

**Вариант 3:** воспользуйтесь методом [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
stack["Country_3"] = \
    np.where(stack["Country_1"]=="Russian Federation", stack["Country_2"], stack["Country_1"])
```

---

результат:

```
In [167]: stack
Out[167]:
            Country_1           Country_2      Country_3
0       United States  Russian Federation  United States
1  Russian Federation          Uzbekistan     Uzbekistan
2            Bulgaria  Russian Federation       Bulgaria
3  Russian Federation               Spain          Spain
4  Russian Federation          Montenegro     Montenegro
```

---

PS метод `.apply()` стоит использовать только в том случае если вы не можете найти другого векторизированного решения. В подавляющем большинстве случаев решение, использующее `.apply(...)` окажется медленнее других **векторизированных** решений.

Answer (score 3):

Покажу вариант, как исправить всё-таки `apply` (хотя он и не оптимален):

```
def function(row):
    if 'Russian Federation' in row['Country_1']:
        return row['Country_2']
    else:
        return row['Country_1']

stack['Country_3'] = stack.apply(function, axis=1)
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. я пыталась сделать так: stack['Country_3']=np.where('Russian' in stack['Country_1'],stack['Country_2'],stack['Country_1']). При этом в новый столбец добавились значения только из столбца Country_1. Не подскажете ли, в чем тут ошибка?

Comment: @Olga Это видимо не мне вопрос, а MaxU, тогда вы комментарий не к тому ответу написали, перенесите его туда )

Comment: @Olga, ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать скалярные операции при работе с векторами. При работе с Pandas/Numpy нужно научиться мыслить векторами и матрицами вместо скаляров и циклов. ;) Если вам нужно проверка по __подстроке__, то это можно сделать так: `stack['Country_3']=np.where(stack['Country_1'].str.contains('Russian'),stack['Country_2'],stack['Country_1'])`